# What is the "+" symbol for the drag term encoded in a TLE?

Tags: two-line-elements

I have two TLE, the drag term for the first TLE is `-26868-1`, which I suppose equals to `-0.026868`. But on the second TLE, we have `00000+0`. What does the "+" symbol represents here?

```
COSMOS 2549             
1 47546U 21008A   21040.52165678 -.00037182  00000-0 -26868-1 0  9998
2 47546  67.1483  54.1721 0006757 284.8888  75.1223 13.96668399   985

TJS-6                   
1 47613U 21010A   21036.34392819  .00000403 -56594-6  00000+0 0  9998
2 47613  28.3962   6.0839 7309460 180.1054 196.4507  2.28168883    27
```

Comment: My guess is that you place the decimal point towards the right. For example, `12345+1` will give `1.2345` opposed to `12345-1` which gives `0.012345`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While this was too rushed out question, in the mean time I managed to find an answer while playing with already existing TLE parsers.

The main difference between the `+` and `-` sign is that `-` multiplies whatever is left of the sign with 10 to the **negative** value, while the `+` multiplies whatever is left of the sign with 10 to the **positive** value.

Example:

If we have the drag term `-26868+1`, the extracted value is `-2.6868`. But if we have the drag term `-26868-1`, the value is `-0.026868`.

From Celestrak's [What is the format for the two-line element sets?](https://celestrak.org/columns/v04n03/#FAQ01):

> Fields 1.10 and 1.11 have a somewhat different format that the other fields. **In particular, they use a modified exponential notation with an implied leading decimal point. This convention is inherited from FORTRAN where all such numbers range from 0 to less than 1.** The first six columns of each field represent the mantissa and the last two represent the exponent. For example, the value -12345-6 corresponds to -0.12345 × 10<sup>-6</sup>. Each of these two fields can be blank, corresponding to a value of zero.

From NASA Spaceflight's [Definition of Two-line Element Set Coordinate System](https://spaceflight.nasa.gov/realdata/sightings/SSapplications/Post/JavaSSOP/SSOP_Help/tle_def.html):

> Second Derivative of Mean Motion
>
> (00000-0 = 0.00000) The second derivative of mean motion is a second order drag term in the SGP4 predictor used to model terminal orbit decay. It measures the second time derivative in daily mean motion, divided by 6. Units are revs/day^3. **A leading decimal must be applied to this value. The last two characters define an applicable power of 10. (12345-5 = 0.0000012345).**
>
> Drag Term
>
> (67960-4 = 0.000067960) Also called the radiation pressure coefficient (or BSTAR), the parameter is another drag term in the SGP4 predictor. Units are earth radii^-1. The last two characters define an applicable power of 10. Do not confuse this parameter with "B-Term", the USSPACECOM special perturbations factor of drag coefficient, multiplied by reference area, divided by weight.

Comment: Exactly. You could just write up the extended, implicit number, e.g -0.26868 * 10^1.

Comment: @uhoh thank you for the edit, will pay more attention next time!

Comment: It's also always okay to accept your own answer. I usually wait a few days to see if others have additional answer or comments.